# I have tries to write a c program using alarm function I am using it for first time but my ouput is not as per desired can someone help me with that

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, computer-science, alarm

Write a C program simulating alarm clock. In the main function, you fork a child process,
and the child process sleeps for 5 seconds (the number of seconds is an command line
argument, see below for a sample run) , after which the child process sends the signal
(SIGALRM) to its parent process. The parent process, after forking the child process,
pause, upon receiving the SIGALRM signal, and prints out a message “Ding!”. The
following is a sample run

$ ./alarm 5

alarm application starting

waiting for alarm to go off

<5 second pause>

Ding!

done

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void Dingdong()
{
    printf("Ding!");
    exit(1);
    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    
    if(argc!=3)

    {
        printf("How much seconds you want to sleep the child process\n");
    }

    int PauseSecond=(argv[1]);
    
    {
        if(fork()==0)
        {
            printf("waiting for alarm to go off\n");  
            printf("%d second pause",PauseSecond);
            sleep(PauseSecond);
            kill(getpid(),SIGALRM);
        }
        else {
            printf("Alarm application starting\n", getpid());  
            signal(SIGALRM,Dingdong);
            printf("done");
        }

    }   
    



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's keeping it from working at all:

1. `int PauseSecond=(argv[1]);` That puts the address of the first argument in `PauseSecond`, which will usually be some really big number. You probably wanted to parse the value of the first argument instead. You need to use something like `atoi` or `strtol` on it to do that.
2. You're calling `getpid()` after forking, so the child is sending the signal to itself instead of to the parent. Either call `getpid()` before the fork and save it to a variable, or call `getppid()` instead.
3. The parent process is finishing execution and exiting before the child process's sleep ends. You can add the `pause()` function to the parent process to make it wait for a signal handler to run.
4. If you want `done` to print, you can't call `exit` from the signal handler.

Just fixing the above will get the program sort of working, but there's other things you should consider fixing too:

1. Since you're not using `argv[2]` for anything, you should see if `argc` is 2 instead of 3.
2. If there aren't enough arguments, you should exit/return instead of continuing and trying to use one that's not there.
3. You should either put a `\n` on the end of `"%d second pause"` or do a manual `fflush`, or you won't see that until after the sleep.
4. `printf("Alarm application starting\n", getpid());` Your format string won't actually show the result of that `getpid()`.
5. If you do want to exit from the signal handler, you need to use `_Exit`, not `exit`, as the latter isn't async-signal-safe.